# How to merge two data frames with repeated values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in pandas:

```
  dilevery_time   dispatch_time  source_lat  source_long  Address   name
0 21:39:37.265    21:47:37.265   -73.955741    40.3422     Dmart    John
0 21:39:37.265    21:47:37.265   -73.955741    40.3422     Dmart    John
```

And other one is:

```
  chef_name   dish_name   dish_price   dish_quantity   ratings
0   xyz        Chicken      120            1             4
1   abc        Paneer       100            2             3
```

I want to join these two dataframes in pandas. I have performed concatenation but its not allowing me to perform because first dataframe has repeated values.

So, I have done this:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner', axis=1)
```

But this gives me following output:

```
   dilevery_time  dispatch_time  source_long   Address  name  chef_name  
0  21:39:37.265   21:47:37.265    -73.955741    Dmart   John   xyz
0  21:39:37.265   21:47:37.265    -73.955741    Dmart   John   xyz

  dish_name   dish_price    dish_quantity    ratings
0  Chicken      120             1                4
0  Chicken      120             1                4
```

And I want it in this format:

```
   dilevery_time  dispatch_time  source_long   Address  name  chef_name  
0  21:39:37.265   21:47:37.265    -73.955741    Dmart   John   xyz
0  21:39:37.265   21:47:37.265    -73.955741    Dmart   John   abc

  dish_name   dish_price    dish_quantity    ratings
0  Chicken      120             1                4
0  Paneer       100             2                3
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in first dataframe you have index 0 twice. You could use `reset_index` method and then get your result:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]: 
  chef_name dish_name  dish_price  dish_quantity  ratings
0       xyz   Chicken         120              1        4
1       abc    Paneer         100              2        3

In [10]: df1
Out[10]: 
  chef_name dish_name  dish_price  dish_quantity  ratings
0       xyz   Chicken         120              1        4
1       abc    Paneer         100              2        3

df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace

In [11]: pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner', axis=1)
Out[11]: 
  chef_name dish_name  dish_price  dish_quantity  ratings dilevery_time  \
0       xyz   Chicken         120              1        4  21:39:37.265   
1       abc    Paneer         100              2        3  21:39:37.265   

  dispatch_time  source_lat  source_long Address  name  
0  21:47:37.265  -73.955741      40.3422   Dmart  John  
1  21:47:37.265  -73.955741      40.3422   Dmart  John
```